# Don't remove some container while doing docker-compose stop

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I have 10 containers running.

I have a docker-compose file to spin up all of them at once.

But when I do `docker-compose stop` I want to **stop only 7 of them** and 3 needs to be running.

How can I do this ?

Comment: you can down all container and up again few container also using `docker-compose up -d test`

Answer (score 0):

You can assign those 7 containers in your compose file a profile.
Here is some information for you: https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/

Alternatively, you can just pass the names of each container to the stop command.

I.E docker-compose stop container1 container2 ...